# Why am I getting non-deterministic results with Repeat()

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm trying to expand my knowledge on Rx. So I'm just playing around with streams and try to make them behave as I would expect them to do.

While I have read bevor that the Repeat() operator has difficulties in practice because you could loose notifications between the OnCompleted and the re-subscription, I can't figure out on my own why the following happens.

```
        var subject = new Subject<string>();

        var my = subject
            .Take(1)
            .Merge(Observable.Empty<string>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)))
            .Repeat();
        my.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => subject.OnNext("1 at " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () => subject.OnNext("2 at " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () => subject.OnNext("3 at " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), () => subject.OnNext("4 at " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () => subject.OnNext("5 at " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6), () => subject.OnNext("6 at " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

When I run this example the results are totally non-deterministic:

Result 1:

```
1 at 1006
3 at 3007
5 at 4995
```

It's good that it left out the 2  and 4 but even inside this result there is some strangeness because actually between the 3 and the 5 is no real 2 seconds gap.

However, the results can be even worse. See this one:

```
1 at 1003
2 at 2003
4 at 4005
6 at 6004
```

There is no 2 seconds gap between 1 and 2. It's exactly one second. Why didn't he left it out?

If anyone could clarify things for me, I would be more than happy!

**EDIT**

I just noticed that it might be the Merge that is wrong here. If I refactor my query to Concat things seem to happen as they should:

```
        var my = subject
            .Take(1)
            .Concat(Observable.Empty<string>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)))
            .Repeat();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows (and other desktop OSes) is not a runtime OS and so you can't rely that its timers will be precise down to milliseconds. And especially if you have more timers, this can lead to non-deterministic behavior, which is exactly your case.

This is how your original sequence works:

- time ~ 0

  - `Take(1)` subscribes to `subject`
  - timer for the delayed empty observable starts ticking
- time ~ 1

  - 1 is added to `subject`, 1 is written out; after this point, nobody subscribes to `subject` anymore
- time ~ 2

  - timer for the delayed empty observable runs out. Because of that, `Take(1)` subscribes to `subject` again and another timer for delayed empty observable starts
  - at about the same time, `2` is added to `subject`

Because of slight differences in timing, the two actions at time approx. 2 can happen in any order. And the order matters, either 2 is added before `Take()` resubscribes or before. And thus, 2 can be written out, or not.

If what you want is a sequence like this:

1. wait for first item and return it
2. wait about two seconds
3. wait for second item and return it (ignoring any that were added during the two-second wait)
4. …

then I think the code in your edit is right.

But this in no way guarantees deterministic results. On my computer, if I change the wait time of the delayed empty observable to 1960 ms, I get non-deterministic results when using `Concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2c in late to the party; if you are looking for determinism for testing, then you should use the TestScheduler instead of the real ThreadPool/TaskPool/NewThread schedulers. Purely for the reasons that Svick points out (OS scheduling rocks the boat).